# weak convergence in $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $e_n = (0,0,\dots,1,0,0,\dots)$,(i.e. the n-th component is 1). Show that $e_n\rightharpoonup 0$ in $\sigma(\ell^{\infty},(\ell^{\infty})')$. I'm having trouble because the dual of $\ell^{\infty}$ is not $\ell^1$. Could someone give me some ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you can't use the direct argument for $1 \le p < \infty$. Have you tried contradiction? This gives you an $x' \in (\ell^\infty)'$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ with $| x'(e_{n_k}) | \ge \varepsilon$ for some subsequence. Can you use this to construct $x \in \ell^\infty$ that exploits the $e_n$?

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Thank you so much! Shouldn't have forgotten contradiction.

Comment: You can use a direct argument.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in some sense, $l_1$ is 'enough' of a dual for the purposes of this problem!

Suppose $f$ is a linear functional, let $g_k = f(e_k)$.

Choose $x_k$ such that $|x_k| = 1$ and $f(x_k) = |f(e_k)| = |g_k|$.

By choosing $y_n = (x_1,...,x_n,0,...)$ we see that $\|y_n\| = 1$ and
$|f(y_n)| = \sum_{k=1}^n |g_k| \le \|f\|$  and so 
$g \in l_1$ and hence $f(e_k) = g_k \to 0$.

**Aside**: Not that it helps here, a little more work shows that any element of the dual $f$ can
be written as $f=g+h$ where $g \in l_1$ and $h = 0$ on $c_0$.

Comment: @daw: My answer was incorrect, thanks for pointing that out. I have repaired it.

Comment: I would see this answer from the following perspective: Since $e_n \in c_0$ (space of null sequences with $\ell^\infty$ norm), it is sufficient to consider the restriction $f_{|c_0} \in (c_0)^* = \ell^1$ of $f \in (\ell^\infty)^*$. And to show $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$ in $c_0$ uses the 'classical argument'.

Comment: @copper.hat How do you get $x_k$ such that $|x_k|=1$ and $f(x_k)=|f(e_k)|$?

Comment: @VictorHugo multiply $e_k$ by a suitable complex scalar.

Comment: @copper.hat thank you!